# View( ) function in R: How to view part of huge data frame as spreadsheet in R

Tags: r, view, dataframe, rstudio

I have a huge data frame `df`  in R. Now,if I invoke `View(df)` then Rstudio does not respond since it's too big. So, I am wondering, if there is any way to view, say first 500 lines, of a data frame as spreadsheet.

(I know it's possible to view using `head` but I want to see it as spreadsheet since it has too many columns and using `head` to see too many columns is not really user friendly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see first 100 lines of the data frame `df` as spreadsheet, use

`View(head(df,100))`

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the dataframe as a matrix such as df[rowfrom:rowto, columnfrom:columnto], for example in your case:

```
df[1:500,]
```